# Conflict between jQuery and Bootstrap Star Rating (emojis form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a feedback form:
- the 1st part of the form uses emoji rating
- the 2nd part uses a picture and the "bootstrap star rating" plugin

But it seems there is a conflict when I put these 2 parts together.

Here is how the form is expected to look like:
[Expected Form (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdNZx.jpg)

**EDIT 10/02/2018**
Robert explained that jQuery shall be loaded before Star Rating, like this:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/js/star-rating.min.js'></script>
```

-> This solves the errors in the developer console

The first part of the form gets messy: [problem Case A (picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ralVu.jpg).
Result can be seen here: http://www.ju-lehadventure.com/feedback_A.html

**EDIT 10/02/2018**
Robert, I'm not sure about how the copies of the `rating` should be removed. I've done a few tests but it didn't work... 
When I remove the `class` completely, it looks closer to the expected layout (no more disruption from the "star rating" plugin) but the radio button becomes visible and the emojis don't turn yellow when selected...

This is what I modified (feedback_A_2.html):

```
    <div class="ratingItemList">
      <input id="rating1-1-2" type="radio" value="1" name="rating1"/>
      <label class="rating rating1-1" for="rating1-1-2"><i class="em em-angry"></i></label>
      <input id="rating1-2-2" type="radio" value="2" name="rating1"/>
      <label class="rating rating1-2" for="rating1-2-2"><i class="em em-disappointed"></i></label>
      <input id="rating1-3-2" type="radio" value="3" name="rating1"/>
      <label class="rating rating1-3" for="rating1-3-2"><i class="em em-expressionless"></i></label>
      <input id="rating1-4-2" type="radio" value="4" name="rating1"/>
      <label class="rating rating1-4" for="rating1-4-2"><i class="em em-grinning"></i></label>
      <input id="rating1-5-2" type="radio" value="5" name="rating1"/>
      <label class="rating rating1-5" for="rating1-5-2"><i class="em em-heart_eyes"></i></label>
    </div>
  </label>
```

result can be seen here: http://www.ju-lehadventure.com/feedback_A_2.html

**What would be the right way to modify the code?**

I tried to keep the first `rating` and remove the other ones but -> only the 1st emoji was disrupted and other ones were having the radio button...

Actually, I do not understand the use of all these classes "rating rating1-1", "rating rating1-2", etc. Where could I get more info about this?

Thanks!

**--- end of EDIT ---**

**feedback_A.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" >

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Feedback Form</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' 
href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/css/star-rating.min.css'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/feedback_1.css">

</head>


<body>

<form class="rating-wrapper">

  <label class="rating-label">
  <span style="font-size: 21.0pt; color: #3870c4">What did you think of:</span><br/><br/>
  the services provided by the agency (itinerary, booking process, organization)?

<div class="ratingItemList">
  <input class="rating rating1-1" id="rating1-1-2" type="radio" value="1" name="rating1"/>
  <label class="rating rating1-1" for="rating1-1-2"><i class="em em-angry"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating1-2" id="rating1-2-2" type="radio" value="2" name="rating1"/>
  <label class="rating rating1-2" for="rating1-2-2"><i class="em em-disappointed"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating1-3" id="rating1-3-2" type="radio" value="3" name="rating1"/>
  <label class="rating rating1-3" for="rating1-3-2"><i class="em em-expressionless"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating1-4" id="rating1-4-2" type="radio" value="4" name="rating1"/>
  <label class="rating rating1-4" for="rating1-4-2"><i class="em em-grinning"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating1-5" id="rating1-5-2" type="radio" value="5" name="rating1"/>
  <label class="rating rating1-5" for="rating1-5-2"><i class="em em-heart_eyes"></i></label>
</div>        

</label>       <label class="rating-label">the services provided by the staff during the trip (guide, driver, cook, etc.)?

<div class="ratingItemList">
  <input class="rating rating2-1" id="rating2-1-2" type="radio" value="1" name="rating2"/>
  <label class="rating rating2-1" for="rating2-1-2"><i class="em em-angry"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating2-2" id="rating2-2-2" type="radio" value="2" name="rating2"/>
  <label class="rating rating2-2" for="rating2-2-2"><i class="em em-disappointed"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating2-3" id="rating2-3-2" type="radio" value="3" name="rating2"/>
  <label class="rating rating2-3" for="rating2-3-2"><i class="em em-expressionless"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating2-4" id="rating2-4-2" type="radio" value="4" name="rating2"/>
  <label class="rating rating2-4" for="rating2-4-2"><i class="em em-grinning"></i></label>
  <input class="rating rating2-5" id="rating2-5-2" type="radio" value="5" name="rating2"/>
  <label class="rating rating2-5" for="rating2-5-2"><i class="em em-heart_eyes"></i></label>
</div>

 </label>

<label class="rating-label">
<span style="color: #3870c4">How likely would you recommend Ju-Leh Adventure to your friends?</span><br/><br/>

</label>



<div class="example-03">

         <input id="input-03" value="0">
</div>



  <div class="feedback">
    <textarea name="textarea" placeholder="What would you like to share with us?"></textarea>
    <button class="submit">Send Your Feedback</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-star-rating/4.0.1/js/star-rating.min.js'></script>

 <script  src="js/feedback_1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script  src="js/feedback_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


 </body>

 </html>
```

**feedback_1.css**

```
    @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700");
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #edf0f5;
  color: #002125;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.rating-wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.rating-wrapper .rating-label {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: block;
}
.rating-wrapper .ratingItemList {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1em 0;
}
.rating-wrapper input.rating {
  display: none;
}
.rating-wrapper label.rating {
  padding: 5px 3px;
  font-size: 32px;
  opacity: .7;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
          filter: grayscale(1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.rating-wrapper label.rating:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0.84);
          filter: grayscale(0.84);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
          transform: scale(1.15);
  -webkit-transition: 100ms ease;
  transition: 100ms ease;
}
.rating-wrapper input.rating:checked + label.rating {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
          filter: grayscale(0);
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
          transform: scale(1.15);
}

.feedback {
  width: 100%;
}
.feedback textarea, .feedback input {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 90%;
  display: block;
  margin: .5em auto;
  padding: .5em;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #d2d3d8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.feedback textarea:focus, .feedback textarea:active, .feedback input:focus, .feedback input:active {
  border-color: #3870c4;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #3870c4;
          box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #3870c4;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms;
  transition: 100ms;
}
.feedback textarea {
  height: 100px;
}
.feedback button {
  margin: 1em auto;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.disputelab_logo {
  width: 140px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -70px;
}

button {
  color: #edeef0;
  background-color: #9b9ea9;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial sans-serif;
  border: 0;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

button.not-disabled {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3870c4;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #214375;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button.not-disabled:hover {
  background-color: #2d599c;
  -webkit-transition: 100ms;
  transition: 100ms;
}




@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 310px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 267px;
    height: 63px;
  }
}  

@media screen and (min-width: 310px) and (max-width: 315px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 272px;
    height: 64px;
  }
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 316px) and (max-width: 320px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 277px;
    height: 65px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 325px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 282px;
    height: 66px;
  }
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 326px) and (max-width: 330px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 287px;
    height: 67px;
  }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 331px) and (max-width: 335px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 292px;
    height: 68px;
  }
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 336px) and (max-width: 340px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 297px;
    height: 70px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 341px) and (max-width: 345px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 302px;
    height: 71px;
  }
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 346px) and (max-width: 350px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 307px;
    height: 72px;
  }
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 351px) and (max-width: 355px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 312px;
    height: 73px;
  }
}  
@media screen and (min-width: 356px) and (max-width: 360px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 317px;
    height: 74px;
  }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 365px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 322px;
    height: 75px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 366px) and (max-width: 370px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 327px;
    height: 77px;
  }
}   
@media screen and (min-width: 371px) and (max-width: 375px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 332px;
    height: 78px;
  }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 376px) and (max-width: 380px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 337px;
    height: 79px;
  }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 381px) and (max-width: 385px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 342px;
    height: 80px;
  }
} 
@media screen and (min-width: 386px) and (max-width: 390px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 347px;
    height: 81px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 391px) and (max-width: 395px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 352px;
    height: 82px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 396px) {
  .example-03 img {
    width: 357px;
    height: 84px;
  }
```

**feedback_1.js**

```
$('button.submit').disabled = true; // disable button on load

// Enable button
function enable_submit() {      
$('button.submit').disabled = false;      
$('button.submit').addClass('not-disabled');    
}    

// Disable button

function disable_submit() {      
$('button.submit').disabled = true;      
$('button.submit').removeClass('not-disabled');    
}

// Display feedback after rating 

$('.rating').on('click', function() {
  var rating = this['value'];

$('.feedback').css('display', "block");
  feedback_validate(rating);
});


// Enable or disable button by validation

function feedback_validate(val) {
  if (val <= 0) {
    disable_submit();  
  } 
  else if (val > 0) {
    enable_submit();
  }    
}
```

**feedback_2.js**

```
$(function(){ 

    $("#input-03").rating({
        min:0, max:4.5, step:0.5, size:'xs',
        showClear: false,
        clearCaption: '',
        stars: 1,
        emptyStar: '<img src="img/prayer_flags_bw.jpg" />',
        filledStar: '<img src="img/prayer_flags.jpg"  />',
        starCaptions: {
            0.5: 'highly unlikely',
            1: 'very unlikely',
            1.5: 'moderately unlikely',
            2: 'slightly unlikely',
            2.5: 'neutral',
            3: 'slightly likely',
            3.5: 'moderately likely',
            4: 'very likely',
            4.5: 'extremely likely',
        }
    });
});
```

Image files:
- [prayer_flags.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhJWb.jpg) 
- [prayer_flags_bw.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy5PP.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you look at your developer console you'll see a few errors related to your loading jQuery *after* Star Rating; the former relies on jQuery to function so it really must be loaded after jQuery...

Comment: Hello Robert, thank you for your answer.

Ok, so this means that CASE B should be excluded.

For Case A, on feedback_A.html, it looks like the "bootstrap star rating" plugin disrupts the part of the form with the emojis... But I don't know what to modify to avoid this issue... any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: It's expanding in that fashion because you're applying `display:flex` to `ratingItemList` in your CSS file.  I'm not sure why each wrapper of `ratingItemList` contains 5 different copies of the `rating` as that's ALSO causing issues... removing all but the first seems to result in the expected layout.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Unfortunately I didn't manage to do it... See "edit 10/02/2018" above.